# Assertion error for BytesIO object in Python unittest

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have a core logic classes like below:

```
class SomeDBTManifestProvider:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def extract_manifest_json(self, file_stream: BytesIO):
        try:
            zipf = zipfile.ZipFile(file_stream)
            manifest_json_text = [zipf.read(name) for name in zipf.namelist() if "/manifest.json" in name][0].decode("utf-8")
            return json.loads(manifest_json_text)
        except Exception as e:
            raise FetchManifestJsonException(e)


class DbtProvisioner(object):

    def __init__(self, dbt_manifest_provider: SomeDBTManifestProvider):
        self.dbt_manifest_provider = dbt_manifest_provider
        
    def provision(self, provision_request: ProvisionRequest):
        self.dbt_manifest_provider.extract_manifest_json(BytesIO(b'ABC'))
        return "Success"
```

Where `ProvisionRequest` is nothing but a `DataClass` and it can be ignored for now. As it can be seen `DbtProvisioner` is dependent on `SomeDBTManifestProvider`, therefore I have used D.I to access the method of `SomeDBTManifestProvider`. Now, I want to test `DbtProvisioner` for which I wrote the below test case:

```
def test_dbt_provision(self):
        provision_request = ProvisionRequest(
            DataProduct("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", {}, [{}]), Workload("ab", "cd", "ef", "gh", DbtAttr("path"))
        )
        dbt_manifest = Mock()
        actual = DbtProvisioner(dbt_manifest).provision(
            provision_request)
        dbt_manifest.extract_manifest_json.assert_called_with(BytesIO(b'ABC'))
        self.assertEqual("Success", actual)
```

Now, using the above approach I want to ensure that my method has been called with the right set of arguments. But somehow, it is giving me the below error:

```
Expected: extract_manifest_json(<_io.BytesIO object at 0x10d675900>)
Actual: extract_manifest_json(<_io.BytesIO object at 0x10f8efef0>)
```

How do I resolve this error? What am I missing here?

I also referred to multiple articles from SO but didn't help in any way. TIA

Comment: btw, pretty sure there is a bug in `extract_manifest_json`.... you do `json.loads(manifest_json_text)` but `manifest_json_text` is a list created on the previous line with a list comprehension.... this should raise a `TypeError`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `BytesIO` objects do not compare to each other based on content, but identity, so while `b'ABC' == b'ABC'` is true, `BytesIO(b'ABC') == BytesIO(b'ABC')` is not because they are two different `BytesIO` objects.

To perform your test as desired, a workaround would be to use the `getvalue` method to extract the value of the `BytesIO` object used as the argument of the call, which can be found in the `mock_calls` attribute of the `Mock` object.

Change:

```
dbt_manifest.extract_manifest_json.assert_called_with(BytesIO(b'ABC'))
```

to:

```
self.assertEqual(dbt_manifest.extract_manifest_json.mock_calls[0].args[0].getvalue(), b'ABC'))
```

Comment: I might be wrong but can you help me to understand that I was actually trying to use `assert_called_with` to check if it accepts the right arguments instead you have suggested a way where I compare the content instead of checking that method is called at least once with the right set of arguments. What am I missing here?

Comment: `mock_calls[0]` returns the first call made with the mock object, and then `args[0]` returns the first argument of the call, which, if it's a `BytesIO` object, should have a `getvalue` method that you can call to return its content for comparison. So it effectively performs an `assert_called_with` call manually with the ability to compare  based on content rather than identity.

Comment: Cool. understood. Thanks a lot for that detailed description @blhsing